# Java Thread Pool Executor

Tags: java, priority-queue, threadpoolexecutor

I am doing a reminder application.

I have the jobs in the priority queue.

The sample job object is `{job_id : 1001, epoch : 1514140200000}`.

The task is to make the job execute in that epoch time.

I am planning to dequeue a job from the queue and assign a thread to it and schedule it to run in that epoch time. Is there a way to do it or is that the correct way to do?

Comment: Please expand and clarify your question; you're not providing any code we can check.

Comment: @MartínStraus I haven't written any code. I need to know if it is the correct way to do. Only then I can proceed to code.

Comment: It's simpler to know what you mean by your description if you code it. Translate your description to code, and we might help.

Comment: Would you consider using some kind of schedulers like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org)

Comment: @Veera Is it possible to set epoch time for a job in quartz scheduler?

Comment: If you can't use epoch time to schedule a job, you can easily convert the epoch time to whatever Quartz uses.

Comment: @phenomenal - Please do go through the examples and documentation. From what I understand (and mentioned by @Jim), you could always convert the epoch time to a Date object which Quartz seems to accept. Also, please do post the solution that you have created to solve this problem once you have been able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via Java thread pools, see the ScheduledExecutorService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

That has a nice sample, but basically you can schedule tasks to run at particular times or after a particular delay.

Libraries like Quartz (as someone notes) provide lots of other options.

Comment: Is it possible to set epoch time for a job in quartz scheduler?

Comment: The executor service doesn't provide a "run at this exact time" function (if you happen to be writing for Android, it provides extra functions that do). You'd have to write that translation yourself, or use Quartz.